# Trocar letra por número em C

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando programar um algoritmo de telefone com as teclas antigas onde o usuário irá informar as letras como entrada e na saída irá me devolver em forma de números. Observe um exemplo abaixo:

Entrada: Hello-World

Saída: 43556-96753

Tentei com o código abaixo, porém só me retorna o número da primeira letra da palavra

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char texto[30];

    printf("Pressione A B C para 2");
    printf("\nPressione D E F para 3");
    printf("\nPressione G H I para 4");
    printf("\nPressione J K L para 5");
    printf("\nPressione M N O para 6");
    printf("\nPressione P Q R S para 7");
    printf("\nPressione T U V para 8");
    printf("\nPressione W X Y Z para 9");
    printf("\n\nInforme as letras: ");
    gets(texto);

    char *ptr;
    ptr = strtok(texto, "-");

    while (ptr != NULL){
        if (*ptr == 'A' || *ptr == 'B' || *ptr == 'C'){
            printf("2");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'D' || *ptr == 'E' || *ptr == 'F'){
            printf("3");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'G' || *ptr == 'H' || *ptr == 'I'){
            printf("4");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'J' || *ptr == 'K' || *ptr == 'L'){
            printf("5");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'M' || *ptr == 'N' || *ptr == 'O'){
            printf("6");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'P' || *ptr == 'Q' || *ptr == 'R' || *ptr == 'S'){
            printf("7");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'T' || *ptr == 'U' || *ptr == 'V'){
            printf("8");
        }
        else if (*ptr == 'W' || *ptr == 'X' || *ptr == 'Y' || *ptr == 'Z'){
            printf("9");
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL, "-");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código nem compila, e usa coisas que não deveriam mais ser usadas, e ainda é complexo demais, sem sequer fazer o que parece querer. Se quer que apresente o número para todas as letras deve fazer isso com cada uma e não apenas com a primeira letra da palavra como fez. Tem que varrer o texto inteiro caractere por caractere, não vejo sentido em usar `strtok()`. E falou transformar em maiúsculo para garantir que a conversão ocorra mesmo se digitado minúsculo. Dá para simplificar mais, mas está bom assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char texto[30];
    printf("Pressione A B C para 2");
    printf("\nPressione D E F para 3");
    printf("\nPressione G H I para 4");
    printf("\nPressione J K L para 5");
    printf("\nPressione M N O para 6");
    printf("\nPressione P Q R S para 7");
    printf("\nPressione T U V para 8");
    printf("\nPressione W X Y Z para 9");
    printf("\n\nInforme as letras: ");
    scanf("%s", texto);
    for (int i = 0; texto[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char letra = toupper(texto[i]);
        if (letra == 'A' || texto[i] == 'B' || letra == 'C') printf("2");
        else if (letra == 'D' || letra == 'E' || letra == 'F') printf("3");
        else if (letra == 'G' || letra == 'H' || letra == 'I') printf("4");
        else if (letra == 'J' || letra == 'K' || letra == 'L') printf("5");
        else if (letra == 'M' || letra == 'N' || letra == 'O') printf("6");
        else if (letra == 'P' || letra == 'Q' || letra == 'R' || letra == 'S') printf("7");
        else if (letra == 'T' || letra == 'U' || letra == 'V') printf("8");
        else if (letra == 'W' || letra == 'X' || letra == 'Y' || letra == 'Z') printf("9");
        else printf("%c", texto[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EMfHfi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wynnoqcx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ScanAndCompare.c).

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma outra solução bem reduzida baseada na tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char texto[30], result; int i = 0;
    printf("Pressione A B C para 2");
    printf("\nPressione D E F para 3");
    printf("\nPressione G H I para 4");
    printf("\nPressione J K L para 5");
    printf("\nPressione M N O para 6");
    printf("\nPressione P Q R S para 7");
    printf("\nPressione T U V para 8");
    printf("\nPressione W X Y Z para 9");
    printf("\n\nInforme as letras: ");
    scanf("%s", texto);
    while (texto[i] != '\0'){
        result = tolower(texto[i]) > 96 && tolower(texto[i]) < 122 ?  (char)((20 - tolower(texto[i]) / 122) + (5 * tolower(texto[i]) / 16)) : texto[i];
        printf("%c", result);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/qkUAu1)